# setting img path in .htaccess after redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have redirected in `.htaccess` file to point to my themes index page which is situated in `../themes/theme_name/index.php` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /themes/theme_name/
RewriteRule ^themes/theme_name(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^themes/theme_name themes/theme_name%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But my img folder is in route but because of the redirect in .htaccess file it now tries to call the images from `../themes/theme_name/img/` instead of `../img/`

How may i set the path to point to img folder in .htaccess file please?

Comment: add before the last rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?img/ [NC]`

Comment: @Deadooshka Dont know if you could help me again please. Now the images are being displayed from the correct file and locations but when i upload a new image via $_post     $t = time();
 $NewImageName = "$t$ImageName";
    copy($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], "../img/header_images/$NewImageName"); it goes to thems/theme_name/img/header_images oppose to the main root/img/header_images folder

Comment: So if POST requests also not needed to rewrite, add this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET` also before the last rule.